# Why does the rejection not bubble up?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If `function uploadLogs()` is rejected, I expect the rejection to bubble up and be handled by `function reject(reason)` but it doesn't. Why not?

A rejection handler for `function uploadLogs()` handles the rejection:

```
    return EventCollector.persist().then(function persistResolve() {
        return EventCollector.uploadLogs().then(function uploadLogsResolve() {
            return closeApp();
        }, function rejectionHandler() {
            console.log("this rejection handler handles the event")
        });
    }, function reject(reason) {
        return closeApp();
    });
```

But if I remove the rejection handler and expect the rejection to bubble up and be handled by the rejection handler of `persist()`, it for some reason doesn't.

```
    return EventCollector.persist().then(function persistResolve() {
        return EventCollector.uploadLogs().then(function uploadLogsResolve() {
            return closeApp();
        });
    }, function reject(reason) {
        console.log("rejection is not handled when uploadLogs() fails");
        return closeApp();
    });
```

Isn't promise chaining and rejection bubbling supposed to work this way?

Comment: Can you give more context than just saying fails. the reject function get called when ever the promise that is returned from uploadLogs() is rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The success or rejection handlers are called based on whether *their* promise resolved successfully. But their children are called inside their success functions, which means that at that point it is already decided that the parent function is a success, so there is no reason to suddenly fail the parent function, just because something the child does is a failure.

So no, it's not supposed to work that way, any more than it would have if you were to replace the promises with a regular synchronous setup. You wouldn't expect this to behave like you expected with the promises, right?

```
if( persist() ) {
  if( upload() ) {
    closeApp();
  }
  else {
    console.log('This would obviously not go into the below else for persist().');
  }
}
else {
  closeApp();
}
```

This is roughly the behavior that a promise simulates, just in an asynchronous manner.